# The “less info” pane on user profiles in Meta is unreadable

Tags: bug, design

At the top of user profiles on Meta, there’s a “less info” button:

> [image]

*CLICK!*

> [image]

The labels next to the items are unreadable, the colour is almost the same as the white background.  By comparison, e.g. on ServerFault:

[image]

The labels "reputation" "badges" and so on are easily visible.

I can reproduce on latest Safari and Chrome on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Reproducable on IE9 as well, FWTW.

Comment: Repro on both FireFox and IE11 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Repro on Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for surfacing this. It's been passed on to the SE design team.